# Does a photon have an amplitude of motion at a speed less than the speed of light?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

In the book **QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter**, Richard Feynman writes that for a photon there are nonzero amplitudes of motion with a speed that is greater or less than the speed of light. However, at great distances they are so small that they can be neglected.

Amplitude of motion with a speed less than the speed of light corresponds to the components of the photon propagator, which correspond to massive virtual pairs?

Comment: canyou give the page number as the online pdf's are images

Comment: Pages 89-90 https://ibb.co/WPvB16L https://ibb.co/xsHwsfp

Comment: Thanks. Feynman always was sui generis., (the two times I heard him lecture (1964 and 1981)). I will be interested in the answers,

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10967/how-is-the-path-integral-for-light-explained-or-how-does-it-arise this question and answers may help

Comment: @Joshua Lin Thanks, but there I did not find the answer (

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178938, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571421,