# Can particles actually pop out from vacuum and annihilate each other?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, antimatter, virtual-particles

Can particles actually pop out from vacuum and annihilate each other? Or is it just a mathematical trick?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual particles and physical laws](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109229/)

Comment: @ATR welcome to Physics Exchange!  have you searched for anything relating to your question, or read some reference?  and can you clarify what you mean by "pop out from vacuum" ?  also, try to keep the question as 1 question - if it's not very very closely related questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are no perfect Euclidean spheres in reality, yet we use them as models for things in physics. Mathematical objects are the products of human imagination. They are not real. Every application of mathematics to physics is a "trick".

Carefully selected mathematical objects sometimes prove to be excellent representations of reality. But the reality lies in physics experiments and observations, not in the mathematics. The math of vacuum fluctuations has been checked by experiments like the [Lamb-Retherford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift#Lamb%E2%80%93Retherford_experiment) experiment, and found to be a good match to reality.

*Nothing* in your physics textbook actually happens: it's all models. Want reality? Go do experiments.