# Do all the conservation laws of Physics take no time to propagate?

Tags: conservation-laws, faster-than-light

For instance, conservation of momentum, does it take time to propagate between two or more objects?

If it does, then there would be some moment that the momentum is not conserved.

If it doesn't take any time at all, since the law itself is information, then doesn't it prove that information can travel faster than light?

Comment: Conservation laws are manifestations of the continuous symmetries present in our laws(read more about Noether's theorem). They're abstractions. They're not physical entities that have attributes like speed of propagation. You're making a categorical mistake in thinking this way.

Comment: It is worth noting that the way we treat collisions in an introductory course---as a black boxes which happen on very short time scales and the details of which are ignored---misses exactly those features of real collisions that "transmit" the conserved quantities in finite time. That could lead to the impression the momentum leaps instantly from one extended object to another, but this is not a feature of proper understanding of what is happening in even very simple collisions.

Comment: I think you have something fundamentally backwards: 'laws' are just expressions of the human understanding of how the universe works, so thinking that they 'propagate' is one of those "not even wrong" ideas.

Comment: I like to think of conserved quantities as being properties *of the observer*. It bears no need to mention that quantities like total energy are in fact relative to a frame of reference. But I think of it as a fundamental limit on what an observer is capable of seeing. An observer will never see the total amount of energy change, so if he sees there being more energy in one part of the system, he can immediately conclude there is less in the other. In that sense, they take no time to propagate, whether as a result of logical inference or its more extreme manifestation, quantum entanglement.

Comment: An interesting consequence of certain potential modes of time travel is conservation laws hold locally but not globally.

Comment: If I point a flashlight at Mars, then turn it on, how long does it take before the Martians know the photons my flashlight emits travel at light speed?

Comment: I don't understand your logic. Even if the law was an equation written on a piece of paper that needed to be communicated to the whole universe, this communication would have already occurred before any interaction was to happen. It's not even "not even wrong"...

Comment: What a great question!

Answer (score 66):

Conservation laws don't "propagate". They are *inevitable consequences* of symmetries of the dynamics by [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), and the dynamics propagate with whatever finite speed they do.

Comment: In other words: Conservation laws hold everywhere, at all times. There is no need for them to propagate, they are a *fundamental property of physics*.

Comment: @Neuneck That's a wonderful concise rendering of the answer.

Comment: To make it even more concise: conservation laws hold *locally*, so they involve no propagation. Note that local laws can usually be re-cast into global laws. For example, local charge conservation can be re-cast as a statement that the current flowing into a volume must be equal to the current flowing out of that volume plus the time rate of change of total current inside the volume.

Comment: Related : http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103724/44080

Comment: Well you did not include the speed @ACuriousMind. It would have to be at the speed of light.

Answer (score 33):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation - I was just writing some text there that I think helps explain.

> Continuity equations are a stronger, local form of conservation laws.
>   For example, the law of conservation of energy states that energy can
>   neither be created nor destroyed—i.e., the total amount of energy is
>   fixed. But this statement does not immediately rule out the
>   possibility that energy could disappear from a field in Canada while
>   simultaneously appearing in a room in Indonesia. A stronger statement
>   is that energy is *locally* conserved: Energy can neither be created nor
>   destroyed, *nor* can it "teleport" from one place to another—it can only
>   move by a continuous flow. A continuity equation is the mathematical
>   way to express this kind of statement.

If conservation of energy *only* said that total energy is fixed, and energy actually *could* teleport, then your question would be a very important question. But actually, every conservation law in practice is the stronger type, a *local* conservation law. Energy can only move by a continuous flow, and same for momentum and anything else.

A flow of energy, just like a flow of any other physical quantity, moves at or below the speed of light.

Comment: Does continuity apply in the context of quantum mechanics? What about disentanglement and "action at a distance"?

Comment: There is no such thing as just "continuity", there are a wide variety of "continuity equations" describing many different quantities. Energy and momentum are conserved in quantum mechanics, and yes, those conservation laws are written as continuity equations in quantum mechanics too. There is no conflict between entanglement (which is ubiquitous in QM) and these continuity equations. I'm not sure why you think there would be. Can you explain what you have in mind?

Comment: I mean something like: two entangled particles are separated by a considerable distance. Is the measure of each particle's energy also in superposition? When the states of the particle(s) is measured, does it determine how much energy is in one location (and how much in the other)?

Comment: Yes, you can have two distant entangled particles (called an EPR pair), where one is more energetic and one is less energetic, but it is not determined which is which until you measure them. You can look online or in an intro QM textbook for an explanation of why information does not flow faster than light when you measure an EPR pair. This information-flow issue is commonly discussed. Well, energy *also* does not flow faster than light when you measure an EPR pair ... and it's for the exact same reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't mean to split hairs on the definition of "flows," but it's funny that you said energy can't "teleport," while a common name for the entanglement phenomenon is, well, "teleportation."

Comment: Another question: We can't (in principle) actually observe every interaction that preserves the local conservation of energy, can we? Yet, if we know (from prior measurement) the total energy of the system and measure the energy in part of it, we, by logical inference, immediately know the energy of the other part. It's a bit like entanglement, and just as "instant." In the context of the question, it would be more interesting to explain why this (and entanglement) isn't actually information moving faster than light.

Comment: In my EPR pair example, there is a more energetic particle and a less energetic particle, but it is not determined which is which. If you measure the energy of one, you can immediately infer the energy of the other. But this does not require or imply that either information or energy is moving faster than light. Why would it? See http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/3163/3811 for more details, for example.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: a common _name_ may be teleportation, but there's a good reason that we use mathematics instead of prose in physics.

Comment: Conservation of energy is violated in long distances because time symmetry is broken.

Answer (score 17):

Conservation laws do not propagate instantaneously (or really at all), it really means that some property of the system does not change over time.

In the case of momentum conservation, the *information* about the collision propagates (at most) at the [speed of sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound) in the medium. This is why you see the cars continuing along their path during a collision:

[image]

If the information of the crash travelled instantaneously, then the rest of the car would not move forwards after the front of the car impacts the wall, which is not what we see here. So no faster than light information travelling here.

Comment: What a gruesome example! It reminds me of our physics professor, ranting about students overtaking him on the way to the lecture, who will probably fail the momentum questions later at the exam...

Comment: Errr... correct me physics noob if I am wrong, but: The momentum conservation is what makes the dummy keep going forward while the car around him is decelerating, spending its momentum in deforming the front section. (Until the dummy hits something, like the windshield, and spends *its* momentum in deforming that, or itself.) There is no need for anything propagating anywhere, much less limited to the speed of sound in the medium. The dummy *has* momentum, and it is conserved until applied forces change that. I don't see how "information about the impact" is propagating anywhere. Poor example?

Comment: _"If the information of the crash travelled instantaneously, then the driver (and the rest of the car) would not move forwards after the front of the car impacts the wall."_ What force would make the driver stop?

Comment: @DevSolar: That is the issue at hand. OP expects that it takes no time for the information to propagate, which would suggest that the driver would not move during the collision (car stops, so does the driver). Since it is clear he does, then it takes time for the information of the collision to pass to the driver for their reaction.

Comment: @JiK: The impulse of the collision, obviously. But that'd only be in the case of instantaneous information passing; since that's *not* the case, it only provides *more* evidence that the signal speed is not infinite.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I think you're making a central mistake in that example. The driver doesn't collide with the wall *at all*. He's colliding with the steering wheel, and the windshield. The "information" that the *car* collided with the *wall* is irrelevant. Just the deceleration of the car (making the steering wheel and windshield an obstacle) is relevant.

Comment: @DevSolar: The dummy doesn't collide with the wall because there is about 4 feet of steel & 1/4 inch piece of glass in front of it. But I see your point. I'll amend the answer to discuss the rear wheels moving forwards after the point of contact.

Comment: The speed of sound in the car frame is around 3000 m/s. This answer seems to say that if a 5 meter car hits the wall traveling 30 m/s (108 km/h), the rear of the car will travel approximately 5 cm before coming to a full stop.

Comment: @JiK: I say *...propagates (**at most**) at the speed of sound...* At best, the *shortest* distance the car would go would be that.

Comment: @KyleKanos The speed of the propagation of information tells only when the rear of the car starts possibly decelerating. The magnitude of deceleration, and thus the time it takes for the rear to stop, does not depend on the speed of information at all. You say "If the information of the crash travelled instantaneously, then the rest of the car would not move forwards after the front of the car impacts the wall" but that is not true.

Comment: @KyleKanos: The rear wheels are starting to *decelerate* immediately. They keep moving because a) inertia, and b) forward parts of the car deforming. This is actually by design, because it makes surviving the crash much easier. If e.g. a tank hit a suitably reinforced wall, the front would *not* deform significantly, the rear would stop more or less immediately, and everybody inside would be dead, full stop (pun intended). This has nothing to do with "information propagation" and everything with "crumple zone".

Comment: @KyleKanos: You can actually observe that in your animation: The moment the crumple zone is "used up" and the rather non-crumpling engine block hits the obstacle. Notice how the deceleration of the remaining vehicle spikes sharply at that point...

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at an example, electromagnetism.

The electromagnetic field (the combination of electric and magnetic fields) has momentum.

Charges have momentum.

The charge feels a force right where it is, a force based on the fields right where it is. This changes the momentum of the particle.

The field loses an equal and opposite amount of momentum and also does so right in the same place. (The field has momentum distributed in little bits all over space, so has momentum right there to give to the charge.) Technically there is just a flow of momentum from the fields to the charge because the charge is also just changing its momentum at a certain rate, nor all at once. So you can also think of it as the charges momentum being given to the field in a way where it starts to spread out through the field into larger and larger regions. Since momentum has a direction there is no objectivity about whether you lose $p_x$ or gain $p_{-x}.$

So momentum propagates through space, and can be stored in the electromagnetic field and flow through space via the flow through the electromagnetic fields (and yes, technically the fields have a momentum and a flow of momentum) in a conserved way up until it meets a charge at which point the momentum in the field is no longer conserved but the total momentum (field and charge) is conserved.

Momentum is conserved locally. And it can take time for momentum to get from one object (charge) to another object (charge). But when it does so, momentum it is still conserved in the time in between because in between, the fields have the momentum.

Same with energy.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained that they don't propagate.  That's a real puzzler though, and the real question is how does the stuff (energy, charge, whatever) always add up when a transfer takes finite time?

The answer to figuring that out was a profound pillar of modern physics: the *field* contains momentum (etc.).  So while an electron is handshaking with another charged particle to say "you go this way, I'll go that way", you have the further puzzle of relativity of time as there is no "simultaneous" in an absolute sense.  One changes before the other, or vice versa, in different reference frames.  The solution is that the electric field (electromagnetic, if you are using relativistic effects) contains the momentum that is not at the moment (in your frame of reference) ascribed to either particle.

I'm sure I butchered that, but you get the idea:  **fields are real things that carry these properties**, not just a way of drawing maps.

Answer (score 1):

All conservative **phenomena** (not laws), do indeed, take a finite time to propagate, therefore "information" can't travel faster than light.  Also, just because phenomena take time to propagate, does not mean that the phenomena are not being conserved at any given instant of time.  In fact, there is **no moment**, when the phenomena are not conserved!